# How to get response from Sidekiq Worker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backgroundworker, sidekiq, sidekiq-monitor

I am new to Sidekiq background job world. I have successfully setup Sidekiq with redis and it's working fine. I am wondering how to get response from Sidekiq Job or worker when it will complete ? Actually I want to display all successful jobs with some useful info about it like it's arguments. Is possible to do this without any extension gem?

Extras ::

- I want to trigger email when job will complete

Thanks in advance :-)

**EDIT**

Still I am looking for correct answer but meanwhile I used this hack: I create entry in separate table named sidekiq status when any worker class is called. If I want the status then I run queries on this table.

Reviews and suggestions are welcomed :-)

Thanks @ralph for suggestions..

Comment: You can use the gem sidekiq-status to see the status of the worker and trigger when done

Comment: yes but I want to do it without any extension gem. Is it possible ?